# How can i build image section in flutter with let's say +3 more?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have more than 4 photos to include in my property info page. How can I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far ?

Comment: I am confused how to do this, so any initiative would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to render max 4 items and 1st will get max screen width. To have overlay I used `Stack`

You can follow this widget,

```dart
class TestWidgetL extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidgetL({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestWidgetL> createState() => _TestWidgetLState();
}

class _TestWidgetLState extends State<TestWidgetL> {
  int numberOfGrid = 12;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          final screenWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
          final screenHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
          return ListView(
            // use customScrollView
            children: [
              // imagePart

              //0th index
              if (numberOfGrid > 0)
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/image01.png",
                  width: screenWidth,
                  height: screenHeight * .25,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),

              if (numberOfGrid > 1)
                Row(
                  children: List.generate(
                    numberOfGrid > 4
                        ? 3
                        : (numberOfGrid - 1) < 0
                            ? 0
                            : (numberOfGrid - 1),
                    (index) => Stack(
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/image01.png",
                          width: screenWidth / 3,
                          height: screenWidth / 3,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        if (numberOfGrid > 4 && index == 2)
                          Positioned.fill(
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.white12,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "+${numberOfGrid - 4}",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 33,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "Photos",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 23,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              Slider(
                  value: numberOfGrid.toDouble(),
                  min: 0,
                  max: 22,
                  onChanged: (v) {
                    setState(() {
                      numberOfGrid = v.toInt();
                    });
                  })
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

find more about widget and UI on [flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)